# Use MultipleChoiceField for Integerfield in form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

### Situation

I have a model class with integer field(= scored_place_number).

I want uses to choose either 1, 2 or 3 for the field that I set the form field as

```
forms.MultipleChoiceField # set it to IntegerField
```

in a form.

### Problem

The form is displayed fine but when the form is submitted by tapping a submit button, django displays error.

```
Enter a list of values
```

It won's show when I did't specify forms.MultipleChoiceField so I'm guessing something is wrong with combining integer field with MultipleChoiceField.

### Question

How can I use forms.MultipleChoiceField for IntegerField of Model?

### Code

Model

```
class ComparisonScore(models.Model):
    comparison   = models.ForeignKey(Comparison, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_place  = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name="scored_place",   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    second_place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name="unscored_place", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    scored_place_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Form

```
class ComparisonScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ComparisonScore
        fields = '__all__'

    scored_place_number = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=(
            ('neither', 0),
            ('first_place',  1),
            ('second_place', 2)
        )
    )
```

View

```
class CreateComparisonScoreView(CreateView):
    model = ComparisonScore
    form_class = ComparisonScoreForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('comparison:index')
```

Comment: check my answer bellow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the first items in your tuples as Integer, these are the first items that define the Field Type:

```
scored_place_number = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=True,
    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    choices=(
        (0,'neither',),
        (1,'first_place'),
        (2,'second_place')
    )
)
```

Comment: You don't need to send a list of digits, that's what MultipleChoiceField does, replace `MultipleChoiceField()` to `ChoiceField()`, since you're using RadioSelect, and note `IntegerField()` will never accept a list, but an Integer. I updated my answer, check it @Bigair

Comment: It did WORK!! Thank you for your help.